# Where can I find the xap files for the Office Web applications?

Tags: silverlight, ms-office

I am using the new Office Web applications. s it using Silverlight? If so, where can I find the xap file for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office Web Apps are only using Silverlight for resizing display, not for conversion. So even if you got the XAP, it wouldn't really tell you anything you don't already know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see all of the traffic - look for the XAP request and you'll find the XAP at that location.  Then directly download the file by typing the full address to the XAP in your browser.

Comment: I tried this but did not see any xap file. Did you have more success? If so, could you please post the URL?